# using pagination in serializer django

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am working on a django project in which I am trying to fetch all the products having `update_ts` field greater than `product_sync_ts` from `Product` table from the server at a time, but since the number of products is large this requires a large amount of time to fetch all data.I am also returning the current time stamp along with the data.Now I want to paginate the results.

**My Previous code :**

*Views.py*

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def productlist(request, format=None):
    product_sync_ts = request.GET.get(
            'product_sync_ts', None)
    if product_sync_ts:
        product =Product.objects.filter(
            update_ts__gt=product_sync_ts)
        )
        serializer = SyncedProductSerializer(
            instance={'products': product})
        return response(serializer.data)
    else:
        content = {'details': "Bad Request"}
        raise APIException400(request, content)
```

*serializer.py*

```
class SyncedProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    product_sync_ts = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        method_name='get_current_ts'
    )
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('products', 'product_sync_ts')

    def get_current_ts(self, obj):
        product_sync_ts = datetime.utcnow().isoformat(' ')
        return product_sync_ts




class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        method_name='change_image_url'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'unit',
            'price',
            'image_url'
        )

    def change_image_url(self, obj):
        return ''.join([
            CDN_URL, str(obj.image_url)
        ]) if str(obj.image_url) else None
```

**How I tried modifying it for pagination :**

*Views.py*

```
class PaginatedProductList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        product_sync_ts = request.GET.get(
            'product_sync_ts', None)
        if product_sync_ts:
            product = GrProduct.objects.filter(
                update_ts__gt=product_sync_ts
            )
            paginator = Paginator(product, 1000)
            page = request.GET.get('page')
            try:
                 product = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                 product = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                 product = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

             serializer = SyncedProductSerializer(
                 instance={'products': product})
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            content = {'details': "Bad Request"}
            raise APIException400(request, content)
```

This is working fine, I am getting paginated results,but the problem is that I'm not able to send the next and previous page information to the client. The client has no way to know what are the valid(non-empty) number of pages.

Can someone suggest me how can I modify my code in order to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example how to paginate results with an `APIView` class and `PageNumberPagination` pagination class :

```python
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class ProductList(APIView, PageNumberPagination):
    # number of items per page by default
    page_size = 1000
    # max number of items per page
    max_page_size = 1000

    def get_queryset(self):
        product_sync_ts = self.request.GET.get('product_sync_ts', None)
        if product_sync_ts:
            products = GrProduct.objects.filter(update_ts__gt=product_sync_ts)
            return self.paginate_queryset(products, self.request)

        raise APIException400(request, {'details': "Bad Request"})

    def get(self, request):
        products = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = SyncedProductSerializer(instance={'products': products})
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Read [DRF - PageNumberPagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination) to configure your pagination

Comment: Also how can I add page_size and current_page_number along with next and previous??

Comment: I wanted to customise the get_paginated_response method but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right or not

Comment: Hey man, create an other question to explain clearly your issue. I'm gonna take a look :)

Comment: Yeah I figured out how to solve it..thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 3):

There is [`GenericAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) which has `get_paginated_response` method which returns

```
return self.paginator.get_paginated_response(data)
```

So you just need to subclass this Mixin

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView

class PaginatedProductList(GenericAPIView): # Fixed

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        product_sync_ts = request.GET.get(
            'product_sync_ts', None)
        if product_sync_ts:
            product = GrProduct.objects.filter(
                update_ts__gt=product_sync_ts
            )
            paginator = Paginator(product, 1000)
            page = request.GET.get('page')
            try:
                 product = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                 product = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                 product = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

            serializer = SyncedProductSerializer(
                 instance={'products': product})
            return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data) # <- here it is
        else:
            content = {'details': "Bad Request"}
            raise APIException400(request, content)
```

Comment: It says `AttributeError: 'PaginatedProductList' object has no attribute 'get_paginated_response'`

Comment: Sorry you need to subclass `GenericAPIView` Fixed

Comment: Ok. Just call `get_paginated_response` directly on paginator

Comment: Not working still..are u sure get_paginated_response method still exists in DRF 3.0 because I think they deprecated it.

Comment: Of course http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles