# AttributeError: '' object has no attribute 'page' DRF Pagination

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

This is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38290029/5080347) asked 2 days back. I used Louis Barranqueiro's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38291738/5080347) to solve my problem. 
 Now I want to add current page number as well as page_size in the serialized data. I know I have to customize the [get_paginated_response](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L224) method in `PageNumberPagination` class, but when I do that I get this error:

**My code**

```
 def get_paginated_response(self, data, request):
        # import pdb
        # pdb.set_trace()
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('current', self.get_current_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('results', data)
        ]))

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        product_sync_ts = self.request.GET.get('product_sync_ts', None)
        if product_sync_ts:
            product = Product.objects.filter(....)
            )
            # return self.get_paginated_response(product, self.request)
            return Response(product)
        else:
            content = {'details': "Bad Request"}
            raise APIException400(request, content)


    def get(self, request, format=None):
        products = self.get_queryset(request)
        serializer = SyncedProductSerializer(instance={'products': products})
        # product = self.paginate_queryset(serializer, request)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer, request)
        # return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data, request)
```

**Error:**

```
File "/Users/Documents/content-api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/pagination.py", line 242, in get_next_link
    if not self.page.has_next()
AttributeError: 'PaginatedProductList' object has no attribute 'page'
```

Answer (score 6):

Some one might wanna try:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20,
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',}
```

on settings.py

with a view like

```
class GeneralManagementAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = GeneralManagements.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    renderer_classes = (GeneralManagementJSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = GeneralManagementSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return GeneralManagements.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        print("request ", request)

        serializer_context = {'request': request}
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            page, context=serializer_context, many=True
        )
        print("serializer ", serializer, "serializer.data", serializer.data )
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should call `paginate_queryset` before calling `get_paginated_response`

> Note that the paginate_queryset method may set state on the pagination instance, that may later be used by the get_paginated_response method.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Answer (score 1):

I am just adding my answer to help other users with the same problem they are facing.
Adding to the above statement, it also has a solution to your question in a simpler way.

Just pass **PageNumberPagination** and add **request** in **self.paginate_queryset** method.

```
class PaginatedProductList(APIView, PageNumberPagination):

def get(self, request):
        products = Product.objects.filter(....)
        return self.paginate_queryset(products, request)
```

Answer (score 0):

So finally I found out how to solve this problem..

Below is the code(Simple and silly mistakes that I was doing)

```
class PaginatedProductList(APIView, PageNumberPagination):

    page_size = 1000 #---crucial line
    max_page_size = 1000

    def get_paginated_response(self, data, page, page_num):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('current', page),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('page_size', page_num),
            ('results', data)
        ]))

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        product_sync_ts = self.request.GET.get('product_sync_ts', None)
        if product_sync_ts:
            product = Product.objects.filter(...)
            )
            return self.paginate_queryset(product, self.request)

        raise APIException400(request, {'details': "Bad Request"})

    def get(self, request):
        page = self.request.GET.get('page', 1)
        page_size = self.request.GET.get('page_size', 1000)
        products = self.get_queryset(request)
        serializer = SyncedProductSerializer(instance={'products': products})
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data, page, page_size)
```

Comment: what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Other than inheriting `PageNumberPagination` class in view, try defining your pagination class outside your view(as a separate class) inheriting from `PageNumberPagination`. and mention that class name as `pagination class = YourClassName`. inside your view

```
class PaginationClass(PageNumberPagination):
     page_size = 2
```

and in view,

```
class GeneralManagementAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
     pagination_class = PaginationClass
```